# turtle width and pensize Difference?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

i changed these attribute of turtle and they seem to do the same thing which is make the line drawn bigger or smaller, what's the difference between the two attributes? they seem to be the same thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference, `turtle.width()` is an alias for `turtle.pensize()`. Here is the docstring shown by `help(turtle.pensize)`:

> Help on function pensize in module turtle:
>
> pensize(width=None)
>       Set or return the line thickness.
>
> ```
> Aliases:  pensize | width
>
> Argument:
> width -- positive number
>
> Set the line thickness to width or return it. If resizemode is set
> to "auto" and turtleshape is a polygon, that polygon is drawn with
> the same line thickness. If no argument is given, current pensize
> is returned.
>
> Example:
> >>> pensize()
> 1
> >>> pensize(10)   # from here on lines of width 10 are drawn
> ```